# Additional tooltip information in highcharter stock

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I am currently building an app and I want to have tooltips in a highcharter stock with additional information.

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(time = seq(as.Date("2021-03-10"), length = 10, by = "days"),
                 values = 1:10,
                 additionalInfo1 = LETTERS[1:10],
                 additionalInfo2 = letters[1:10])

#Packages
library(highcharter) #plots
library(xts) #conversion for stock-highchart
library(dplyr) #piping-operator
```

I know how to add additional information to a tooltip when using `type="line"`. This can be done via

```
highchart_line <- hchart(df, "line", hcaes(x = time, y = values), 
                         tooltip = list(headerFormat = "<b> Some Tooltipheader </b> <br/>",
                                        pointFormat = paste0("index: {point.index} <br/>",
                                                             "time: {point.time} <br/>", 
                                                             "additional1: {point.additionalInfo1} <br/>",
                                                             "additional2: {point.additionalInfo2}")))
```

and shows everything fine. The nice thing is that one can supply the whole data and hence has access to the columnnames.

When creating a `type="stock"`, I need to convert the data to an `xts` while only using the times and the values:

```
stockdata_xts <- xts(x = df$values, order.by = df$time)
highchart_stock <- highchart(type="stock") %>% 
  hc_add_series(stockdata_xts, name = "someData",
                tooltip = list(pointFormat = paste0(
                  "point.x: {point.x} <br/>",
                  "point.y: {point.y} <br/>",
                  "point.index: {point.index} <br/>"
                ))) %>% 
  hc_rangeSelector(enabled = FALSE)
```

Is there a way to put additional data for the tooltip in the stock-highchart such that the tooltip looks like the one in the linechart above? Maybe some functionality of the `xts`-object including more attributes for it which I don't know.

The reason why I want to use the `stock`-highchart is the navigator-bar. If there is a way to include the navigator-bar in the `line`-highchart, I would also be thankful. There is also a function `highcharter::hc_navigator`, but the documentation says that it is only applicable to highstocks. (see https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/highcharter/highcharter.pdf , page 50)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the navigator works in stockChart. For such tooltip customization, I think it will be best to use the dedicated formatter API function: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.formatter

Here you can find an article that can help you use JS code in R:
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-highcharts-javascript-syntax-in-r/?fbclid=IwAR1Em2yNUsIJunTRS4IEbUwGksb5PC7LfZATLcyvb7uLS7ZvV7v4-e0L0